# "He speaks better Spanish than I do" or "He speaks Spanish better than I do"

Tags: grammar, word-order

Could you tell me the difference between these phrases if there is any?

> 1. He corrects me because he speaks Spanish better than I do.
> 2. He corrects me because he speaks better Spanish than I do.

I tried to translate those phrases into my native language by Google Translate, but it didn't change the word order. I don't know if both sentences are equal without changing the meaning or it is just the limitation of the translator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is much difference in practice. It could be argued that (1) means that he speaks Spanish more fluently than I do, and (2) that his Spanish is more correct than mine - but I don't think many people would notice the distinction.